# Find records that do not exist in 2nd table, and also the values mapped against them from first

Tags: sql

Hi so this question has been asked before, but I am not only just trying to extract the records that do not just exist in the first table, but also the mapping from the first table where they don't?

Eg.

Assuming I will join using Month and Year--

Table 1:

| Month | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021 |
| 4 | 2021 |
| 5 | 2021 |
| 6 | 2023 |

Table 2:

| ID | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 3 | 2021 |
| 22 | 4 | 2021 |
| 33 | 5 | 2021 |

Output:

| ID | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 6 | 2023 |
| 22 | 6 | 2023 |
| 33 | 6 | 2023 |

Comment: @DaleK done with 1 & 3. For 2, I have tried all the other solutions given in StackOverflow, but can't seem to wrap my head around the additional requirement.

Comment: You are recommended to tag the single RDBMS you are using e.g. if MySQL then tag it. Just don't tag conflicting RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you say and show, you want to cross join all table 2 rows to the table 1 rows that don't have a match in table 2. For the lookup you can use `NOT EXISTS`.

```
select t2.id, t1.month, t1.year
from t1 cross join t2
where not exists
(
  select null
  from t2
  where t2.year = t1.year and t2.month = t1.month
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  
    t2.ID "ID",  
    no_match.MONTH "MONTH",  
    no_match.YEAR "YEAR"  
From  
    Table2 t2  
Inner Join  
    ( Select t1.MONTH "MONTH", t1.YEAR "YEAR" From Table1 t1 Left Join Table2 t2 ON(t1.MONTH = t2.MONTH And t1.YEAR = t2.YEAR) Where t2.YEAR Is Null ) no_match ON(1=1)  
Where  
    t2.YEAR || t2.MONTH <> no_match.YEAR || no_match.MONTH
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Inner Joined Subquery, named "no_match", selects records from Table1 that doesn't exist in Table2. Now, when we have those, we can get all the IDs from Table2 beside the coresponding "no_match" record(s).